# Angular setting title when redirecting to parent component from child where child is in the parents router-outlet

Tags: angular

So in this Angular (15.0.4) project I've inherited we have a lot of modals that are opened and closed with routerLinks so they function like pages when you redirect to them. Basically you search a list of documents, click one and a modal opens, and when you close it you get back to the list of things. And you can link to them.

Here is the problem. I am currently adding titles to all pages using Title (because this app has different languages), which doesn't work well with this setup. Because when you close the modals the titles stay that of the modals. And I can't just set the title because the same modal can open on different pages. And I don't think I can just set it on close, as the modal can close to different pages.

[Here's](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/restless-fog-35h8jv?file=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts%3A40%2C18-40%2C23) a small example that illustrates it. Though you would have to download it
and run it to see the problem because codesandbox doesn't show titles. (The title starts off as First Parent. When you open modal it becomes Child. And when you close modal it stays child)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I have an answer that works, but I'm not sure how optimal it is.

But this

```
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(navigation => navigation instanceof NavigationEnd),
      filter((navigation: NavigationEnd) => navigation.url === "/parent")
    ).subscribe(() => {
      this.titleService.setTitle(``);
    });
```

Listening to a navigation event to the parent route and setting the title there. (And saving the subscription and unsubscribing on OnDestroy)